# Добавить линию в нижнею часть страницы. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Надо добавить линию расположенную в нижней части страницы.

data.jsp:

```
<div style="width:40%;">
    <table id="paytable" class="display cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>


</div>
```

footeros.jsp:

```
<footeros>
  &nbsp;
</footeros>
```

.css:

```
footeros {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #22c840;
}
```

Возможно проблема в `position`.
`position: absolute | fixed | relative | static | inherit`
Если использовать `position: fixed` ратотает, но при этом полоса всегда находиться в нижней части `экрана` (тем самым занимая часть экрана), а надо в нижней части `страницы`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация на [flexbox](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

HTML

```
<body>
  <main>Some content...</main>
  <footeros></footeros>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
   flex: 1;
}
footeros {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #22c840;
}
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqaMvZ

P.S В демо для кроссбраузерности прошелся через `autoprefixer`

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что Вы хотите сделать. Могу только предполагать, как вариант:
[Пример на jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/v6ys8sqk/)

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Page wrapper</h3>
<div id='page'>
    <table cellspacing="0" border=1> <thead> <tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Gender</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody></tbody> <tfoot> <tr> <th>Total</th> <th></th> <th></th> <th></th> </tr> </tfoot> </table>
    <footeros></footeros>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

footeros {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #22c840;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

А попробуй у `body` сделать просто `border bottom: 50px solid color`, то есть блок растяни на весь экран и присвой ему бордер.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?